# Having Trouble using For Loops to make two triangles of different characters fit into a rectangle?

Tags: java, loops, printing, for-loop, nested

Examples of input:

```
3

4
```

Examples of output (assume that spaces = new lines.)

```
QQQH
QQHH
QHHH

QQQQH
QQQHH
QQHHH
QHHHH
```

So far, the fragment of code that attempts to print this is (Assume that all variables are pre-defined):

```
public int getSize()
{
    for (int i = size; i > 0; i--){
        for (int j = 1; j < size; j++){
            out.print("Q");
            out.print("H");
        }
        out.println("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It just prints: (assume that spaces = new lines.)

```
QHQHQHQHQH
QHQHQHQHQH
QHQHQHQHQH
QHQHQHQHQH
QHQHQHQHQH
```

For input of 5. I'm not quite sure how to make it print only the number of times of its respective integer value. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2):

You could break the inner loop it two, like this:

```
    for (int i = size; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            out.print("Q");
        }
        for (int j = i; j < size + 1; j++) {
            out.print("H");
        }
        out.println();
    }
```

Output:

```
QQQH
QQHH
QHHH

QQQQH
QQQHH
QQHHH
QHHHH
```

Or if you don't want to break the loop, you can use the ternary operator:

```
for (int i = size; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int j = 0; j < size + 1; j++) {
        out.print(j < i ? 'Q' : 'H');
    }
    out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code block instead:

```
int j=0;
for (int i = size; i > 0; i--)
{
    j=0;
    while(j < i) 
    {
        out.print("Q");
        j++;    
    }
    j=i;
    while(j < size+ 1) 
    {
        out.print("H");
        j++;
    }
    out.println();
}
```

Comment: why the down vote?? please let me know the reason, may be I could improve my answer

Comment: You have an infinite loop, and after fixing it, your code still doesn't output the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
 for (int j = 1; j <= size-i; j++) {
   System.out.print("Q");
 }
 for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++) { 
   System.out.print("H");
 }
 System.out.println("");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Tested with sample inputs. Working fine**

```
public int getSize() {
    for (int i = 1; i < size+1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < size+1; j++) {
            int Qtimes = size-i;
            if(j <= Qtimes) {
                System.out.print("Q");
            } else{
                System.out.print("H");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I fixed the code formatting a bit. Feel free to roll it back if it not in your liking.

Answer (score 0):

This works if the input is 4 - for example -change it to any number

```
public int getSize()
{
    int cnt = 0;
    int i,j,k = 0;

    for ( i = 4; i > 0; i--){

        for ( j = 0; j < i; j++){

        System.out.print("Q");

        }
        cnt ++;
        for( k = 0 ; k <cnt ; k++) {
            System.out.print("H");
        }

        System.out.println("");

    }


    return 0;
}
```

output is

```
QQQQH
QQQHH
QQHHH
QHHHH
```